# Retrieve Facebook profile from Xamarin client

Tags: facebook-graph-api, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I would like to get basic user information from Facebook after the user has logged in.

I've looked at the documentation in [How to: Work with authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-work-with-authentication) and under the "How to: Retrieve authenticated user information" section, it shows how to do it from the .NET backend code by using an `HttpClient` to make the call with the AccessToken:

```
var fbRequestUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=" 
        + credentials.AccessToken;
```

Since the mobile client has the accessToken that we get from MobileServices, can the client make the call directly to a Facebook endpoint, or does the client SDK provide us with any built-in functionality?

I've been following the [Xamarin.Forms Sport](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport) project and the way they get the [user information from Google](https://github.com/xamarin/Sport/blob/master/Sport.Shared/Services/GoogleApiService.cs#L28) is by hard-coding the Google endpoint and making a call to get the user info.

Note: Xamarin.Forms Sport uses Mobile Services, not Mobile App, so not sure if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing the server-directed login: where you are making a call to your backend to do the login dance with Facebook.  In this, your client application is making a GET call to .auth/login/facebook, which opens up a browser or the Web Authentication Broker where you enter your credentials.  The end result is you will receive a Zumo access token (different from Facebook access token).

You cannot use the Zumo access token to access Facebook APIs by itself.  In the "How To:" you linked, we show you how to use GetAppServiceIdentityAsync from the backend to get the Facebook access token.  This is possible because you have stored your Facebook client ID via portal, which is available to the backend.

The advantage of doing auth like this was that you don't have to deploy your Facebook Client Id with your mobile apps.  If you wanted to access the Facebook APIs from the client, though, you'll need to get the Facebook token to the client.

Few ways I can suggest:

1. Call .auth/me from your client. The response will give you a JSON object you can parse that should include the FB token associated with your Zumo token.
2. Write a custom API with [Authorize] attribute set that will perform GetAppServiceIdentityAsync and respond with the value of the facebook access token.  You can then parse the response from your client.  This is basically what .auth/me does, but you can write it to give back only your FB access token.
3. Use the Facebook .NET SDK http://facebooksdk.net/ to do client-directed login.  You will get a Facebook token on your client, and then you can use our LoginAsync(Facebook, access_token) method to get a Zumo token so that your client can access both Facebook and your Mobile App backend.  The disadvantage, as I mentioned before, is that you'll have to deploy your FB Client ID with your app.

Comment: I had no idea that the token was not a Facebook access token! I like approach #1 the best. So once I have the FB access token, I would make a call to the "https://graph.facebook.com/me" endpoint from the client to get the user's info?

Comment: One final question, if the FB access token has expired, how would I go about getting a new access token using a refresh token?

Comment: Hi Queti, Currently, we don't support refresh for Facebook.  The reason being that the tokens we get from facebook are extended tokens.  There's currently no support for refreshing extended tokens. Check out this link for more information about extended tokens: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension).  It seems once the extended has expired, your user will login again, but shouldn't have to reenter creds.